# I want to have a admin extension to put store on vacation

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

The way Shopify etc simply allows a static front end page that doesn’t allow people to access your site and you can display custom messages

Like

We are closed for a stock take till 10 june 2018
Or
We are on Easter vacation till xyz

Etc

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding this code to your .htaccess in root directory :

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} 
>201806010000
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} 
<201806300000
 # the page will be displayed from 01 June 2018 to 30 June 2018.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vacation.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/vacation.html [R,L]
```

Here vacation.html is a static page that you should create.